# git error on aosp froyo source code

Tags: android, git, android-source

I want to fetch the Froyo source code from aosp, but I get the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/xxx/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/projects/bootable/diskinstaller.git'
error: Cannot fetch platform/bootable/diskinstaller
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the command you use to fetch the code?

Comment: Are there any non-ascii(created with --force-badname) characters in the "xxx" username? That may be a no go for git

Comment: I followed these instructions: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html with branch -b froyo

Comment: no, there aren't any non-ascii characters in my username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this myself recently. I went and deleted the .repo/projects/bootable/diskinstaller.git and tried again. After a few attempts it succeeded.

Comment: this helped a little, but now repo syncs stops by 99%.
Fetching projects:  99% (157/158)

Comment: when I run repo sync as root I'm able to fetch 100% but then there is an error message: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree ... error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree

Comment: I suggest you now chown -R that directory to yourself then do repo sync. As it has already got the .repo cache, it should just checkout the working files then.